# Changing an isotope filter from within container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope based submenu. When one option is clicked the other option buttons should be filtered out.

It's difficult to explain but you can see it here on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/adamrabbit/YL8gH/42/

In the example when blue is clicked in the color category all the other colors should vanish into thin air! All that should be left in the color category is "show all" and "blue".

For the life of me I can't make it work... but here is what I tried. Please keep in mind that my only experience with javascript is having blazed through the codeacademy courses in the last couple weeks.... so things might look a little off!

This is the latest probably ridiculously overly complicated attempt - my first attempt simply ".hide()" and ".show()" the unused buttons. This code doesn't work, but you can see my thinking.

```
$(function () {
"use strict";

//Define your containers and option sets
var $container = [$('#button-container'), $('#item-container')],
    $optionSets = [$('#button-options .option-set'), $('#item-options .option-set')],
    $value = [{}, {}];

//Initialize isotope on each container
jQuery.each($container, function (j) {
    var isotopeOptions = eval('(' + (this.attr('isotope-options')) + ')');
    this.isotope(isotopeOptions);
});

//Initialize filter links for each option set
jQuery.each($optionSets, function (index, object) {

    var $optionLinks = object.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set'),
            options = [{}, {}],
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
        $value[index][group] = $this.attr('data-option-value');

        // close menu and deselect base option if already selected
        if ($this.hasClass('is-checked')) {
            $container[0].isotope({
                filter: '.xxx'
            });
            $optionSets[0].find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            return false;
        }

        // change classes
        $optionSet.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $this.addClass('is-checked');
        if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') !== 'all')) {
            $optionSet.find('.' + group + 'show').removeClass(group + 'show');
            $optionSet.find('#all').addClass(group + 'show');
            $this.addClass(group + 'show');
        }  else if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') === 'all')) {
            $optionSet.find('.' + group + 'show').removeClass(group + 'show');
        }

        // show all
        if ($value[index][group] === '.reset') {
            $optionSets[0].find('a').each(function (index) {
                $(this).text($(this).attr('name'));
            });
            $container[0].isotope({
                filter: '.xxx'
            });
            $container[1].isotope({
                filter: ''
            });
            $optionSets[1].find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $optionSets[1].find('#all').addClass('is-checked');

            return false;
        }
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        var isoFilters = [
            [],
            []
        ],
            newIsoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in $value[index]) {
            isoFilters[index].push($value[index][prop]);
        }
        var selector = [],
            newSelector;
        selector[index] = isoFilters[index].join('');
        newIsoFilters = isoFilters[0].concat(['.' + group + 'show']);
        newSelector = newIsoFilters.join('');

        if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') !== 'all')) {
            $optionSets[0].find('.is-checked').text($(this).attr('name'));
            options[0][key] = newSelector;
            options[1][key] = selector[1];
        } else if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') === 'all')) {
            options[0][key] = selector[0];
            options[1][key] = selector[1];
        } else {
            options[index][key] = selector[index];
        }
        if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
            // changes in layout modes need extra logic
            changeLayoutMode($this, options[index]);
        } else {
            // otherwise, apply new options
            if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') !== 'all')) {
                $container[0].isotope(options[0]);
                $container[1].isotope(options[1]);
            } else 
                $container[index].isotope(options[index]);

        }
        return false;
    });

});
});
```

Please note - This was forged from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815116/jquery-isotope-multiple-instances-on-the-same-page) and starting from the [fiddle mentioned there](http://jsfiddle.net/YL8gH/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm so impatient for an answer.

Anyway, I got it half mostly working but decided I didn't like the look so I dropped it. The code is still (mostly) useful
http://jsfiddle.net/adamrabbit/YL8gH/34/

the original way without disappearing buttons is here
http://jsfiddle.net/adamrabbit/YL8gH/37/

now it's time to muck about with a sort button.

```
$(function () {
"use strict";

//Define your containers and option sets
var $container = [$('#button-container'), $('#item-container')],
    $optionSets = [$('#button-options .option-set'), $('#item-options .option-set')],
    $value = [{}, {}];

//Initialize isotope on each container
jQuery.each($container, function (j) {
    var isotopeOptions = eval('(' + (this.attr('isotope-options')) + ')');
    this.isotope(isotopeOptions);
});

//Initialize filter links for each option set
jQuery.each($optionSets, function (index, object) {

    var $optionLinks = object.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set'),
            options = [{}, {}],
            key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
            group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
        $value[index][group] = $this.attr('data-option-value');

        // close menu and deselect base option if already selected
        if ($this.hasClass('is-checked')) {
            $container[0].isotope({
                filter: '.xxx'
            });
            $optionSets[0].find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            return false;
        }

        // change classes
        $optionSet.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
        $this.addClass('is-checked');
        if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') !== 'all')) {
            $optionSet.find('.' + group + 'show').removeClass(group + 'show');
            $optionSet.find('#all').addClass(group + 'show');
            $this.addClass(group + 'show');
        }  else if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') === 'all')) {
            $optionSet.find('.' + group + 'show').removeClass(group + 'show');
        }

        // show all
        if ($value[index][group] === '.reset') {
            $optionSets[0].find('a').each(function (index) {
                $(this).text($(this).attr('name'));
            });
            $container[0].isotope({
                filter: '.xxx'
            });
            $container[1].isotope({
                filter: ''
            });
            $optionSets[1].find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $optionSets[1].find('#all').addClass('is-checked');

            return false;
        }
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        var isoFilters = [
            [],
            []
        ],
            newIsoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in $value[index]) {
            isoFilters[index].push($value[index][prop]);
        }
        var selector = [],
            newSelector;
        selector[index] = isoFilters[index].join('');
        newIsoFilters = isoFilters[0].concat(['.' + group + 'show']);
        newSelector = newIsoFilters.join('');

        if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') !== 'all')) {
            $optionSets[0].find('.is-checked').text($(this).attr('name'));
            options[0][key] = newSelector;
            options[1][key] = selector[1];
        } else if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') === 'all')) {
            options[0][key] = selector[0];
            options[1][key] = selector[1];
        } else {
            options[index][key] = selector[index];
        }
        if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
            // changes in layout modes need extra logic
            changeLayoutMode($this, options[index]);
        } else {
            // otherwise, apply new options
            if ((index === 1) && ($(this).attr('id') !== 'all')) {
                $container[0].isotope(options[0]);
                $container[1].isotope(options[1]);
            } else 
                $container[index].isotope(options[index]);

        }
        return false;
    });

});
});
```