# jQuery Isotope 2.0 multiple instances on the same page and Images Loaded integration

Tags: jquery, initialization, jquery-isotope, multiple-instances, imagesloaded

I've been working with Isotope 2.0 jQuery plugin. Reviewing old examples I've found that many options have changed (initialization and so on...). I've found only one working example which works with 2.0 version:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {(function ($) {
        var $container = $('#posts'),
            isotope = function () {
                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.item',
                });
            };
        isotope();
        $(window).on('debouncedresize', isotope);
    }(jQuery));
});
```

Currently I've two questions:
1). How to integrate this script with ***Images Loaded*** plugin. Example from doc won't work because it differs from my init script.
2). I've several div blocks on the site and I'd use them with Isotope independently, in other words the `init` method should consist from one basic script where I could list available containers and that they would you their own independent filter.

How it could be solved?
I've seen similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815116/jquery-isotope-multiple-instances-on-the-same-page) 
but it works only with 1.5.x version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some simplified code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var $container = $('#posts');
   $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
   $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
    });
 });
 });
```

or with your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $container = $('#posts'),
isotope = function () {
  $container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
   });
  };
   $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  isotope();
    $(window).on('debouncedresize', isotope);
}(jQuery));
 });
 });
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Your's script doesn't throw any error messages

Comment: Only last question regarding multiple instances left

Comment: Here is a post that may help [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815116/jquery-isotope-multiple-instances-on-the-same-page).

Comment: Yes, I've seen this. But with 2.0 version or with my updated init script it doesn't work. Placing the var $container = [$('#posts'), $('#posts-new')], for starters instead of var $container = $('#posts'), produces error *** $container.isotope is not a function
 itemSelector: '.item',***

Comment: Here is a simple jsfiddle with 2 isotope containers [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/YL8gH/72/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you help me to finish it with the code from you second example? I've tried in several ways - but had no luck. The last my try doesn't work: $(document).ready(function() {
 var $container = [$('#posts'), $('.example')];
 isotope = function () {
   jQuery.each($container, function (j) {
        this.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.element'
        });

    });   
   $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
   isotope();
  $(window).on('debouncedresize', isotope);
 }(jQuery));
 });